# How to start the new Snipping Tool via run under Windows 11

Tags: run-dialog, windows-11, snipping-tool

Today I finally got the "new" Snipping Tool via Windows Update. In the past, I used `Win + R -> snippingtool` to run the old one, this however doesn't seem to work anymore ("cannot be accessed"):

[image]

According to a [German news site](https://www.golem.de/news/build-22000-132-windows-11-erhaelt-neues-snipping-tool-und-mehr-apps-2108-158881.html), the combination `Win + Shift +  S` works, which I can now verify. However, since humans are creatures of habit:

Is there any easy way to get it to start by typing snippingtool in the run dialog again?

Comment: `Win + Shift +  S` works on Windows 10 (Snip & Sketch), so it should do something, even if it does something else entirely.  What does it do? `Win + R` is the run command, not the Snipping Tool, so I suspect you have the incorrect shortcut.  You have never been able to run the Snipping Tool from the run command.  Yes; I realize I answered your question bout Windows 11, saying it works on Windows 10, the entire point of this comment is to find out if `Win + Shift +  S` does anything on your system.

Comment: [This](https://allthings.how/how-to-use-windows-11-snipping-tool/) matches what I get almost exactly on Windows 10.  Honestly, the only difference is the looks of the icons.  You might want to [edit] your question to be more specific about what is actually happening when you use the shortcut in question.

Comment: Hey @Ramhound - I have no clue why, but `Win + Shift + S` now seems to work although I've tried it a dozen times before. However, the old snippingtool can be started via the `run-dialog` which is started with `Win + R`. I guess this might still be a bug that it doesn't with the new app. Probably, this might be due to the interim phase, who knows.

Comment: Are you sure you actually ran the snipping tool, not Snip and Sketch, with the run command?  I mean starting the Snipping Tool from the Start menu makes complete sense, but you would have to know the name of the executable for the snipping tool, and that seems like more work than select the shortcut in the start menu.

Comment: For Windows 11, I am pretty sure although I cannot remember. However, I just checked it on my Windows 10 PC at work and here it starts the snipping tool. Well, in the end I know that this way of starting programs is a bit different from what other people would do, but I got used to it over the years. I also run notepad, calc or Word via the run command. As I said, force of habit which may come from working too much with Linux severs, I dunno.

Comment: Try snippingtool.exe, works for me on the latest 20H1 build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any easy way to get it to start by typing snipping tool in the
> run dialog again?

Windows 11 newest preview.

Start or Run  (I use Start) and type in snip and the Snipping tool comes up.

There are options in the window but it also tells you to use winkey+shift+S  which is the same in Windows 11 and Windows 10.

Also, the hot keys have a lot of value because you can capture a temporary screen that goes away on any other key press. I use this feature all the time and it integrates nicely with Snag It.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with 21H2 (current Beta). However, I'll check it regularly and if it works, I'll accept your answer, thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: I am on 21H1 (machine A) and Windows 11 (machine B). Snip n' Sketch works as I said on Windows 11. I cannot say for 21H2.  In 21H1 type in snip and there are two possibilities: Snipping tool (deprecated) and Snip 'n Sketch (which come up as before. So it all works - we just need to adapt our steps to the system we have,

Comment: @maio290 - You indicated you were running Windows 11 NOT Windows 10 21H2. I am confused why you brought up Windows 10 21H2.

Comment: @Ramhound It is Windows 11. 

I was a bit confused with the wording of "start" - now I know you meant the startmenu, and here your recommendation works. I guess that's even easier for me than using the run-dialog, therefore I accepted this answer!

Comment: I am not the author of this answer.

Comment: I know, but you cannot mention two persons with @.
I guess it was obvious that only that one sentence was for you. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

explorer ms-screensketch: works in Win11 22H2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).